# Как вставить номер телефона в шапку сайта на платформе битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Как вставить номера телефонов в шапку сайта на платформе битрикс?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно отредактировать шаблон сайта, для начала нужно узнать в настройках какой шаблон используется и после него в файле `header.php` добавить номер телефона.

После того, как узнаете символьный id шаблона, в папках `/bitrix/templates/` или `/local/templates/` найдите папку с данным id и откройте внутри данной папки файл `header.php`